# Android httpUrlConnection connecting to server but not internet

Tags: android, networking, emulation, httpurlconnection

I am working on an application that uses HttpUrlConnection, connects beautifully with the  server, but when fetching data from it says connection time out IOException.

The internet, & network permissions are already set in the android.manifest; there are no bars showing up in the android emulator (does this says anything).

Read at developer.android.com:
The functional limitations of the emulator include:
 - No support for determining network connected state
 - and few others....

Any help will be highly appreciated. And I don't have an actual device to test this.

Received server info do gets printed in the logcat.

Thanks...

Here is the code:

```
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
try {
    Log.i(INFO_TAG, "Received server:" + conn.toString());
    conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", "0");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
    conn.setConnectTimeout(25000 /* milliseconds */);
    conn.setReadTimeout(15000/* 10000 *//* milliseconds */);
    // conn.setDoInput(true);
    // Starts the query
    conn.connect();
    status = conn.getResponseCode();
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Status recevied is: " + conn.getResponseCode());
    responseCode = status;
    if (responseCode == 200) {
        Log.i(INFO_TAG, "URL Connection OK");
        contentIs = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(contentIs));
        String line;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line);
            Log.i(INFO_TAG, "Data Read is: " + line);
        }
    } else {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Could not read data from web server");
        Log.e(ConnectAndGetData.class.toString(),
            "Failed to download content");
    }
}// end of try
catch (Exception ex) {
    // This is currently being printout
    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Received an exception" + ex.toString(), ex);
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw new IOException("Error Connecting" + ex.toString());// "Error connecting");
} finally {
    if (contentIs != null) {
        contentIs.close();
        conn.disconnect();
    }
}
```

One more thing since, it throws a connection timeout exception it does not debug info at this line is printed:
Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Status recevied is: " + conn.getResponseCode());

Comment: Upload your code with question too.

Comment: Hi Lucifer, have uploaded the code with the question :)  I hope someone can hint something here...

Comment: i think i got the answer, try, `conn.close();` instead if `conn.disconnect();` both method has different meaning.

Comment: close is not under httpurlconnection. I am of the opinion that the connection time out exception means it cannot connect. No response code is received too.

Comment: ok do just simple test, open your emulator and open www.google.com , check it, is it opening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not the code above, it was the server code (the main culprit). Now implemented a web service and the code above is working fine.

Thanks all for commenting...

Answer (score 0):

You need to write

`conn.setDoInput( true );` after this line

```
conn.setConnectTimeout(25000 /* milliseconds */);
conn.setReadTimeout(15000/*10000*/ /* milliseconds */);
```

Its Sets the flag indicating whether this URLConnection allows input.

Comment: sorry, to be more clear; I have already tried that but no change

Comment: Hi, so I kind of pin-pointed the problem; the above code can not connect to the server. Any directions? At the server end, it does discovers that the android has connected and the data is sent then.

Answer (score 0):

The emulator can't receive any response from server. I think the problem with your network connection. Check your proxy settings.

Comment: what? I think you meant to ask this: Yes, the server I am using is on the same machine as the emulator.

Comment: Are you using localhost or system IP in your URL string?

Comment: If you using local host you need not to configure any proxy settings otherwise you have to Configure your emulator proxy settings

Comment: sorry, I am reading about this first time what emulator proxy settings, and where?  Internet is accessible from the browser of the emulator and the received server info is identified properly by printing it to logcat. Also, there is no proxy settings within the emulator...

Comment: OK proxy setting is to connect with network, if internet is accessible in emulator no need to change proxy settings.

Comment: @AliRajput you can find proxy settings in "Settings >> Wireless&Networks >> Mobile Networks >> Access point names" You can see a APN named as "Telkila" in emu, go into it and there you can change your proxy if applicable.